# Is it possible to enlarge the / partition without rebooting?

Tags: linux, partition, sfdisk

I can enlarge the root (`/`) partition with `fdisk` without rebooting (deleting an recreating it with the same 1st sector, but greater last sector).

However, I cannot make the kernel to [re-read the partition table](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141476/forced-reread-of-partition-table-difference-between-blkrrpart-and-blkpg-ioctl) :

```
# partx -va /dev/vda
partx: /dev/vda: adding partition #5 failed: Device or resource busy
partx: /dev/vda: error adding partition 5

# kpartx -va /dev/vda
device-mapper: reload ioctl on vda5 failed: Invalid argument
add map vda5 : 0 41492480 linear 0:0 2048

# hdparm -z /dev/vda
/dev/vda:
 re-reading partition table
 BLKRRPART failed: Device or resource busy

# sfdisk -R /dev/vda
BLKRRPART: Device or resource busy
This disk is currently in use.
```

I know what I am doing, and the ext filesystems within the partitions support online enlargement.

Is there a way forcing the kernel to update its partition table?

**EDIT**: I know about LVM, but it is *not* an answer for this question.

Comment: You can try with [partprobe](http://linux.die.net/man/8/partprobe). I don't know if it helps.

Comment: @taliezin I just tried, it doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, take a look at [this](http://www.m1au.com/extending-lvm-root-partition-in-rhel6-without-reboot/).

Comment: I just wonder the unusual name - /dev/vda. But I never tried to enlarge ext online, every operation on partition had to always be done when unmounted. Maybe readonly mount could help you...

Comment: @jaromrax it's from virtualisation such as KVM/qemu

Comment: doesn't the resize2fs tool already do this job?

Comment: Is it duplicate of this [Can I resize the root partition without uninstalling and reinstalling Linux (or losing data)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28122/can-i-resize-the-root-partition-without-uninstalling-and-reinstalling-linux-or)

Comment: @shubham No, this question doesn't involve resizing partitions. It's LVM stuff.

Comment: @Totor, not directly relevant, but you should consider using LVM and not disk partitions.

Answer (score 3):

The kernel will use the old (cached) partition table until you unmount all partitions on the affected disk.

Since you can't unmount and mount the / partition meantime the system is running, the only option you have is a reboot.

Next time try to use LVM, because it allows you to resize volumes (even the root one) without necessitating changing of the partition table.

Answer (score 0):

To online resize the filesystem, especially /, you need to have some form of abstraction between the physical and virtual layer, e.g. LVM.

To live resize with LVM use:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdX
vgcreate vg1 /dev/sdX
lvcreate Root -L10G
```

Then next time the disk is about to be full, you will use `lvextend /dev/mapper/vg1-Root -L+10G --resizefs` and voilà you got more space.

Read up on LVM on http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvm

**EDIT**

To politely ask the kernel to update the partition table which is cached you could try `partprobe`
But I would not assume it to work as you need to, as said earlier, remount all your filesystems, which is hard unless you booted into a live vm.

**EDIT**

You would be able to resize the partition, but that require you to memorize/write down the sizes you see in `fdisk` which can be a very advanced step for everybody. When you have those numbers, you recreate the partition from the begin size and then let it fill the disk.
*this is easier if the partition is the last one on the disk, if you have to resize the middle partition you are certainly out of luck*

I've done it some times for customers, but it is hairy and nerve wrecking job to do.
**I would not recommend this way for safety and data keeping.**

Comment: The question is about partition resizing.

Comment: I fail to see where I haven't answered the question.

Comment: I don't use LVM on my root`/` partition. If I had, it would have been a solution. Also `partprobe` and other similar tools I mention in my question didn't work.