# Delete partition table which resides in kernel memory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, partition, partition-table

I wiped (erased from device) all partitions from a logical volume (lv in LVM). Then I did `partprobe -s` (and other [similar commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141476/forced-reread-of-partition-table-difference-between-blkrrpart-and-blkpg-ioctl): `partprobe` returned no output, `partx` said `partition: none` & `failed to read partition table`). The problem I had is that I could neither do:

- `mkfs /dev/vg/lv` because `/dev/vg/lv is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!`
- `lvremove /dev/vg/lv` the device because `Logical volume vg/lv is used by another device.`

This is because the kernel still sees a partition within the lv block device:

```
# grep dm /proc/partitions
 254        0   85852160 dm-0
 254        1   84850688 dm-1
```

and

```
# ls -lh /dev/dm-*                           
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 254, 0 May 23 14:32 /dev/dm-0                                                       
brw-rw---T 1 root disk 254, 1 May 23 14:08 /dev/dm-1
```

I finally rebooted the machine, which resolved my problem (kernel did not see non-existent partition anymore).

**Do you know a way to solve this without having to reboot?**

Tested on a 3.2 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

LVM devices (or Device Mapper in general) do not support partitions in the same sense as e.g. the `sd` devices do.  With `partx`, you can only manage the normal type of partitions.  On top of LVM devices, partitions must be managed with `kpartx`:

`kpartx -d /dev/vg/lv`

The `kpartx` manpage is a bit terse. To check this, I found a usage example which looks consistent with my assumptions: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=187781

Comment: Next time I run into this problem, I'll try this. It may take several years though. ;)